# How to move a span/ counter across a HTML grid with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, css-tables

I am creating a simple dice game which will eventually become a version of Snakes and Ladders. The counters will take it in turns to roll the dice and move said number of places. If a double is rolled, the user will move back that number of places. I have got a function to get the total number of places to move, but I do not understand how to move the counters across the grid with this information. THE GRID::

```html
<table table-layout: auto; style="width:30%">
    <tr>
        <th id="43">43</th>
        <th id="44">44</th>
        <th id="45">45</th>
        <th id="46">46</th>
        <th id="47">47</th>
        <th id="48">48</th>
        <th id="49">49</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="42">42</th>
        <th id="41">41</th>
        <th id="40">40</th>
        <th id="39">39</th>
        <th id="38">38</th>
        <th id="37">37</th>
        <th id="36">36</th>
    </tr>
    //YOU GET THE IDEA
```

THE COUNTERS::

```html
<span id='pink' class="counter"></span>
<span id="purple" class="counter"></span>
```

I understand how to refer to a field in the grid, but how would I move the counters across this grid based on this information?

```js
dotsNumTotal = (random_index +1) + (random_index2 +1);
    let startingPosition =document.getElementById("myTable").rows[6].cells[0].innerHTML;
```

I understand how to refer to a field in the grid, but how would I move the counters across this grid based on this information? Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please do use `const` and `let` appropriately.
Create a `let idx = 0;`
After a dice roll increment that `idx` by the result i.e: `idx += dicesSum;` Then, to target the specific row and cell you will need some really simple math.
Having an index that goes from 0 to 48, you need to retrieve `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` . *cellIndex * is simple - use Modulo (Reminder) operator `%`. The rowIndex is also simple. Divide the `idx` by the grid width, and go in reverse (subtracting to height and by 1 to get the correct row index).
Since every even row (0-based) has cells going from right to left you need an additional check for that too, easily done using `% 2` on the rowIndex (from bottom)

```js
const elTable = document.querySelector("table");

// Calc grid sizes:
const height = elTable.rows.length;
const width = elTable.rows[0].cells.length;
const size = width * height;


// Function to help get the right table cell where the first  
// (index 0) is at bottom left and the last is at top right
const getCell = (idx) => {
  const rowIndex = height - 1 - Math.floor(idx / width);
  const isRowEven = Boolean((height - 1 - rowIndex) % 2);
  let cellIndex = idx % width;
  if (isRowEven) cellIndex = width - cellIndex - 1; 
  return {rowIndex, cellIndex};
};

// Use like:
let playerIndex = 9; // Remember, indexes start at 0!
// therefore 9 is cell with number 10.
const {rowIndex, cellIndex} = getCell(playerIndex);
elTable.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex].classList.add("active");
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}
td.active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td></tr>
  <tr><td>28</td><td>27</td><td>26</td><td>25</td><td>24</td><td>23</td><td>22</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td><td>13</td><td>12</td><td>11</td><td>10</td><td>9</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
</table>
```

To inversely, get the **index** from a specific cell:

```js
const elTable = document.querySelector("table");

// Calc grid sizes:
const height = elTable.rows.length;
const width = elTable.rows[0].cells.length;
const size = width * height;

// Function to help get the right table cell where the first  
// (index 0) is at bottom left and the last is at top right
const getCell = (idx) => {
  const rowIndex = height - 1 - Math.floor(idx / width);
  const isRowEven = Boolean((height - 1 - rowIndex) % 2);
  let cellIndex = idx % width;
  if (isRowEven) cellIndex = width - cellIndex - 1;
  return {rowIndex, cellIndex};
};

// Inversely, here's the logic to get the index from a clicked cell
const getIndex = (r, c) => {
  const rowIndex = height - 1 - r;
  const isRowEven = Boolean(rowIndex % 2);
  const cellIndex = isRowEven ? width - c - 1 : c;
  const index = rowIndex * width + cellIndex;
  return index;
};

// Use like:
let playerIndex = 0; // Remember, indexes start at 0!
// therefore 9 is cell with number 10.

const setActiveCell = (idx) => {
  const {rowIndex, cellIndex} = getCell(idx);
  elTable.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex].classList.add("active");
};

// Start:
setActiveCell(9);

// To get the index i.e: on click use like:
elTable.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const elTD = ev.target.closest("td");
  if (!elTD) return;
  playerIndex = getIndex(elTD.closest("tr").rowIndex, elTD.cellIndex);
  // Example, apply active cell from playerIndex:
  setActiveCell(playerIndex);
  console.clear(); console.log(`playerIndex: ${playerIndex}`);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
}

td.active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
Click on a table cell to retrieve the index
<table>
  <tr><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td><td>34</td><td>35</td></tr>
  <tr><td>28</td><td>27</td><td>26</td><td>25</td><td>24</td><td>23</td><td>22</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td><td>13</td><td>12</td><td>11</td><td>10</td><td>9</td><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank u you are my new favourite person